# Resources for those beginning to keep Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, product-recommendation, torah-study, adult-learning, baal-teshuva

What are some useful and accessible resources for those who are just beginning to keep the Sabbath? General primers, overviews of the Law, sources of advice on making things easier, and guides to making a traditional Shabbos at home would all be welcomed...as would be sources of Shabbat-related inspiration to read during and before Shabbat. What key books might form a good basic toolkit for beginning Shabbat learning?

Answer (score 5):

Two online resources from Morasha:

[The Shabbat Experience  - Insight into Friday night seudah & mitzvos](http://nleresources.com/nle-morasha-syllabus/jewish-calendar/shabbat-ii-the-shabbat-experience/)

[Shabbat I: Plugging into the Goals of Life](http://nleresources.com/nle-morasha-syllabus/jewish-calendar/shabbat-i-plugging-into-the-goals-of-life/) (basic concepts of Shabbos)

And a book to start with - Lori Palatnik's [Friday Night and Beyond](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0765760673). Here is the Amazon descriptive blurb:

> Friday Night and Beyond is a practical guide to Jewish Sabbath observance. Lori Palatnik walks us through the celebration with an easy-to-follow 'how-to' approach, allowing us to experience a traditional Shabbat. Common questions and concerns are explored by the author, who has also included personal reflections by other individuals on each aspect of the observance.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Here are some resources I would consider useful/practical for those new to Shabbos and seeking to cultivate an Orthodox observance, based on my own experiences as a baalas teshuvah.

**Shabbos primers:**

Broad overviews can be found which aspire to put everything you need to know about Shabbos in one book. Many of these, such as such as Noam Zion's "A Day Apart" and Dayan Dr. I. Grunfeld's "The Sabbath: A Guide to Its Understanding and Observance" are quite beautiful, and mix inspiration and instruction with sound advice about Sabbath practicalities. However, I am not aware of any single book that actually meets the goal of being everything you need for Shabbos. In my experience, these broad overviews are really best suited as sources of uplift and inspiration in one's Shabbos-keeping journey.

**Guides to the Law:**

Beyond a basic breakdown of the 39 melachos such as can be found [online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activities_prohibited_on_Shabbat), I would suggest only a book of piskei din, preferably listed by activity in (English) alphabetical order. It is really important to have a print version of this book so that one can refer to it Shabbos, when one is wondering, as one frequently will, whether it is legal to do something. These books can be hard to find--for some reason, they aren't marketed to baalei teshuvah--but are worth their weight in gold. A short list:

- R'Yaakov Goldstein, *A Semikha Aid for Learning the Laws of Shabbos, vols. 1-3*
- Harav S.Z. Auerbach, *Shemiras Shabbos K'hilchasah*
- Rabbi Dovid Ribiat, *The 39 Melochos: An Elucidation of the 39 Melochos from Concept to Practical Application, vols. 1-4*
- R'Yehoshua Neuwirth, *Shemirath Shabbath, vols. 1-3*
- Rabbi Simcha Bunin Cohen, *The Shabbos Home, vols. 1-2*

If you want shorter, perhaps more accessible guides to start off, books oriented toward children and teens can be a great option. I liked *The 39 Avoth Melacha of Shabbath* by Baruch Chait and *Can I Play Chess on Shabbas* by Joe Bobker.

In the other direction, an excellent and extremely comprehensive guide to the positive and negative mitzvot of Shabbos, including piskei din for every sort of situation imaginable, is the full seven-volume set by Rabbi Cohen: in addition to both volumes of *The Shabbos Home*, mentioned above, it includes *The Shabbos Kitchen*, *Muktzeh: A Practical Guide*, *Radiance of Shabbos* ("The complete laws of the Shabbos and Festival candle-lighting, Kiddush, Lechem Mishneh, meals, Bircas HaMazon, and Havdalah"), *Sanctity of Shabbos* ("A comprehensive guide to the laws of Shabbos and Yom Tov as they apply to a non-Jew doing work on behalf of a Jew"), and
*Aura of Shabbos* ("A selection of relevant Erev Shabbos and Shabbos laws"). A further book of Rabbi Cohen's to add to this collection might be *Shabbat, The Right Way: Resolving Halachic Dilemmas*, which seems to be an extension of *Aura of Shabbos*.

**Guides to Making Shabbos/Positive Mitzvot:**

Although there are a lot of books covering this topic, I think spending Shabbos with frum families is both necessary and sufficient to learn the basics of positive mitzvot, as well as how to make Shabbos. That said, some good books available are these:

- *Shabbos: Tasting Eternity* by Rabbi Daniel Yaakov Travis
- *Friday Night and Beyond: The Shabbat Experience* by Lori Palatnik

Shabbos recipes, as well as guidelines for preparation and service of the traditional Shabbat meals are not too hard to find online. An excellent cookbook including details of Jewish tradition for Shabbos and every day is *Spice and Spirit* by Tzuvia Emmer and Tzipora Reitman.

Laws about reheating and use of the blech may be useful to print before Shabbos from a source like [this](http://nebula.wsimg.com/5d97cd2f36379a4ad44e1db962373f57?AccessKeyId=D35ECF040CB510101C31&disposition=0&alloworigin=1).

**Spiritual and Inspirational Resources:**

I am not qualified to comment on or even list classical writings on the topic of Shabbos. There is a huge body of Shabbos literature, most of which, I am quite sure, is worth reading, although not much of which could be read by beginners without a chavrusa. Personally, what I found to be inspiring in my early days of keeping Shabbos were the remarks on the subject by Herman Wouk (in *This is My G-d*), Jonathan Sacks, and Abraham Joshua Heschel.

**To read/consult during Shabbos:**

In general, all books related to Shabbos are ideal to read and consult during Shabbos: especially at the beginning, Shabbos is an optimal time to learn about Shabbos. But there are some specific things that are useful, if not essential, to have in print for the actual day of Shabbat. The first would be the book of piskei din mentioned previously. Others are:

- A Tanakh broken up into parshios, haftaros, and additional readings by week, ideally with Rashi and/or other commentary (or with a separate book of divrei Torah)
- A siddur or bentcher with the texts of Friday night kiddush, Saturday kiddush, al natilas yadayim/hamotzi, table hymns, bentching, and psalms, ideally including translation and/or commentary
- A siddur with the Shabbos davening: weekday minchah, candle-lighting, kabbalas Shabbos, Shabbos maariv, Shabbos shacharis, Shabbos mussaf, the Torah reading, Minchah, havdalah and weekday maariv. (A "synagogue companion" for Shabbos might also be useful.)
- A songbook with z'miros

...

*Good luck and Gut Shabbos!*

Answer (score 4):

For a guide to the Shabbat Table Experience, try my book, *Treasure of Shabbat: An Illuminated Guide to the Shabbat Table Experience: Finding Meaning and Inspiration through Shabbat Observance at Home*

It is a step-by-step guide to Shabbat celebration at home. Easy instructions gently guide the reader through the Shabbat ceremonies. All Hebrew text is translated and transliterated. Heartening stories and clear explanations enable readers to follow along at someone else's home or celebrate in their own home. Full index. Two thousand source notes. Includes blessing after the meal and food blessings. Illuminated with two hundred color photos.

**Here is the table of contents:**

foreword vi
preface vii
acknowledgments viii
how to use this book x
sample shabbat schedule xiii
list of needed items xv
introduction xvi

FRIDAY AFTERNOON 1
candle lighting 3

FRIDAY NIGHT 11
shabbat angels 13
woman of valor 17
blessing the children 25
kiddush 29
washing the hands 43
blessing on bread 47
the meal 55
songs 61
rest and happiness 63
how cherished is your rest 69
the creator from whose bounty we have eaten 77
creator, master of the world 83
a day for israel 89
blessing after the meal 95

SATURDAY MORNING 97
kiddush 99
washing the hands & blessing on bread 111
the meal 113
songs 117
the source of all blessing 119
this day is honored 127
if i will guard shabbat 133
a day of rest 139
will call freedom 145
blessing after the meal 149

SATURDAY AFTERNOON 151
washing the hands & blessing on bread 153
the meal 155
songs 159
prepare the meal 161
a song of david 165
the spirit's beloved one 167
blessing after the meal 171

SATURDAY NIGHT 173
havdallah 175

BLESSING AFTER THE MEAL 189
introduction 191
a song of ascents 193
washing the hands 197
blessing after the meal 201
addition for festivals 243
addition for chanukah 249
addition for purim 255
invitation after a wedding meal 259
seven blessings after a wedding meal 265
song for a circumcision meal 277
invitation after a circumcision meal 285
addition for a circumcision meal 291

FOOD BLESSINGS 301
introduction 303
blessings before food 305
blessing on grain products 307
blessing on grape wine or grape juice 309
blessing on fruit 311
blessing on vegetables 313
blessing on everything else 315
blessings after food 317
special foods blessing 318
regular foods blessing 326

pronunciation guide 329
glossary 330
photo credits 332
colophon 337
notes 338
index 398

**See more at:**

[https://www.amazon.com/Treasure-Shabbat-Illuminated-Guide-Experience/dp/099849271X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/099849271X)

https://www.amazon.com/author/jonathan.bressel

http://www.jewishlivingpress.com/

Comment: Jonathan Bressel, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for sharing this resource and very properly disclosing your personal interest! I hope you'll stick around and continue sharing your expertise here, perhaps elsewhere among our [tag:shabbat] questions.

Answer (score 0):

Aish has some very nice articles here. http://www.aish.com/sh/?s=nb

Comment: You should summarize and not give the link only.